# EF: how to reuse same filter in both standard query and selectMany

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I am new to EF and LINQ.

The following two pieces of code work:

```
dbContext.Categories.Where(cat => [...big ugly code for filtering...] );
```

&

```
dbContext.Products.Where(prod => prod.PROD_UID == 1234)
                  .SelectMany(prod => prod.Categories.Where(
                                      cat => [...big ugly code for filtering...] );
```

But I want somehow to create only one, reusable, expression or delegate for my filter. I have the following:

```
private static Expression<Func<Category, bool>> Filter(filter)
{
    return cat => [...big ugly code for filtering...] ;
}
```

but I cannot use it in SelectMany.

I am aware that:

- `Where` clause of standard query accepts `Expression<Func<Category,bool>>` and returns `IQueryable<Category>`
- `Where` clause of `SelectMany` accepts `Func<Category,bool>` and returns `IEnumerable<Category>`.

What is the best way to accomplish this? Are any tricks here?

PS: I want in the end to get all categories of a product.

Comment: `Where` applies a filter - `SelectMany` applies a _projection_. Unless your output is a list of `bool`s you can't reuse the same expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analyzing in more detail the SQL generated by EF, I realized that having the filter inside SelectMany is not more efficient.

So, both suggestions (initial one from DStanley and Servy's) should be ok for my case (many-to-many relation between Categories and Products)

```
/* 1 */ 
dbContext.Products.Where(prod => prod.PROD_UID == 1234)
                  .SelectMany(prod => prod.Categories)
                  .Where( Filter );  // reuseable expression
```

this will result into a INNER JOIN

```
/* 2 */ 
dbContext.Categories.Where( Filter )    // reuseable expression
                    .Where(c => c.Products.Where(prod.PROD_UID == 1234).Any());
```

this will result into a EXISTS (sub-select)

The execution plan seems to be absolutely identical for both in my case; so, I will choose for now #2, and will keep an eye on performance.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to use `SelectMany` as a *filter*.  `SelectMany` is used to flatten a collection of collections (or a collection of a type that *contains* another collection) into one flat collection.

I *think* what you want is:

```
dbContext.Products.Where(prod => prod.PROD_UID == 1234)
                  .SelectMany(prod => prod.Categories)
                  .Where(filter);
```

In which case you can reuse the same expression to filter.

**EDIT**

Based on your updated question it looks like you are applying `Where` to an `IEnumerable<T>` property, so the compiler is binding to `IEnumerable.Where` which takes a `Func` instead of an `Expression`.

You should be able to just call `AsQueryable()` on your collection property to bind to `IQueryable.Where()`:

```
dbContext.Products.Where(prod => prod.PROD_UID == 1234)
                  .SelectMany(prod => prod.Categories
                                          .AsQueryable()
                                          .Where(filter);
```

The next option would be to compile the expression to turn it into a `Func`:

```
dbContext.Products.Where(prod => prod.PROD_UID == 1234)
                  .SelectMany(prod => prod.Categories
                                          .Where(filter.Compile());
```

But it wouldn't surprise me if the underlying data provider isn't able to translate that to SQL.

Comment: Thanks... I realized I had a mistake in my code, so I edited it. In the end I want to get a list of categories by product ID

Comment: OK I see.  Just add `AsQueryable()` after `.Categories` to bind the call to `IQueryable.Where`.  I'll amend my answer.

Comment: 1) `AsQueryable` is unnecessary; the entire block of code is inside of an `Expression` (for the `SelectMany`) and so will be able to be translated by the query provider properly, in theory.  2) This isn't addressing the actual question of extracting the big ugly code for filtering out into a `Filter` method.  3) The general approach the OP is making, of a `SelectMany` with a query inside of it that also has some filters is perfectly fine; there's nothing wrong with that fundamental concept at all.

Comment: @Servy I may be misunderstanding the problem, but it seems like the issue is that the compiler is binding to `IEnumerable.Where` instead of `IQueryable.Where` so an `Expression` cannot be used without changing the property to an `IQueryable`.  I hadn't even addressed the fact that the expression was being returned from a method.

Comment: Very strange because when I use your idea with AsQueryable() I get: "Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 1025"

Comment: @Cristi It doesn't surprise me that the query provider doesn't have built in support for the `AsQueryable` method.

Comment: @DStanley While I don't know for sure, I strongly doubt that the query provider is smart enough to see you compiling an expression, ignore the compile method, evaluate the expression variable to its expression, and then use that expression inline.  It's theoretically possible, but I just don't see it happening...

Comment: @DStanley: I am curious about the SQL generated if I would try the filter as you showed in your very first sample code... but I think it will not be as performant as if the filter will be inside SelectMany

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is call the `Filter` function before executing the query and store it in a local variable.  When the query provider sees a method it attempts to translate that method into SQL, rather than executing the method and using the result.  Whenever it encounters a local variable it doesn't attempt to translate it into SQL but rather evaluates the variable to its value, and then uses that value in the query.

As for the problems that you're having due to the fact that the relationship collection isn't an `IQueryable`, it's probably best to simply approach the query differently and just pull directly from the categories list instead:

```
var filter = Filter();
dbContext.Categories.Where(filter)
    .Where(cat => cat.Product.PROD_UID == 1234);
```

Comment: I don't think it will be as performant as SelectMany (based on what I saw using SelectMany looked fine for me)

Comment: @Cristi In theory the queries generated should be the same (or close enough to the same); you are of course free to look at the generated SQL and see if there is a problem with it.  I can't imagine there being a performance problem with this query though.

Comment: I have to try it and come back later

Comment: your last piece of code is wrong... it should be "cat.Products...{something}..." something = where(p => p.PROD_UID == 1234) maybe... which is bit ugly to me

Comment: @Cristi Well, I don't know the details of your specific data mode; I assumed it was a one to many relationship, not a many to many relationship.  Hopefully you're able to adapt this to your specific data model and find a solution, if not, you'll need to provide more details about your data model.

Comment: True, is many-to-many, one category can have more products, but also one product could be in one or more categories. Will give it a try anyway

Comment: @Cristi If it is a many to many relationship then you will need to use that code instead of this one, yes, and it's the conceptually appropriate way to write the query.  If you had improperly mapped a one to many relationship as a many to many relationship through EF, then it would indeed be unnecessarily verbose and conceptually wrong.  The only change is that you'll need to use `Any` rather than `Where`, on `Products`.